# MongoDB collection update attempt gives "identifier starts immediately after numeric literal" error

Tags: database, mongodb, mean

I have a MongoDB collection called "posts" in which a post object looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eb45c2738ae2549000ddb1b"),
    "category" : ObjectId("5e99e61b3b7733f59053e49a"),
    "title" : "Dolorem et inventore aspernatur vel nam.",
    "full_text" : "Id qui iusto. Aspernatur et fugit ut. Sit laboriosam velit. Est magnam aut ipsum corrupti nihil dolor. Similique repudiandae vero deserunt. Dicta voluptate nesciunt.",
    "short_description" : "Aut sint voluptatem et. Vel repellat error eveniet nesciunt perspiciatis et dolor.",
    "updated_at" : "1989-11-02T23:00:00.000Z",
    "created_at" : "1981-11-21T23:00:00.000Z"
}
```

I want to update the `full_text` field of all posts that were created in a year earlier than 2014-07-19 to a certain text (the same for all posts matching the criteria).

For this purpose I did:

```
db.posts.updateMany({ "created_at": { $lt: 2014-07-19T22:00:00.000Z }},{ $set: {full_text: "<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis et dolor at eros tristique tempor at quis erat. Fusce id ante quis lectus blandit porta. Sed erat justo, bibendum blandit sodales vitae, dictum et massa. Integer eget finibus tortor.</p>"}});
```

No update happens and I get a `SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal` error message from CMD.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: warp this data time with double quotes`"2014-07-19T22:00:00.000Z"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's javascript error

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Identifier_after_number

try to use your date as a string like this:

```
"2014-07-19T22:00:00.000Z"
```